# How to insert image in SQLite database from gallery?

Tags: java, sqlite, android-studio

I've been trying to insert an image in sqlite from the gallery. On onCreate I have to check
if the user didn't upload an image yet, it supposed to show an image from drawable, and if he did, it supossed to get the image from sqlite. But it's not inserting.

**This is my Java class**

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_tela_editar_perfil);

    Usuario usuario = getIntent().getParcelableExtra("usuario");


    fotoUsuario = findViewById(R.id.fotoUsuario);
    dao = new ImagemDAO(this);

    Imagem imagem = dao.select(usuario.getNome());

    if (imagem == null) {
        Uri imgUri = Uri.parse("android.resource://my.package.name/" + R.drawable.icone_perfil);
        fotoUsuario.setImageURI(imgUri);


    } else {
        Bitmap bitmap = getImage(imagem.getImagem());
        fotoUsuario.setImageBitmap(bitmap);

    }


    btnVoltar = findViewById(R.id.btnVoltar);
    btnVoltar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(EditarPerfilActivity.this, TelaPerfilActivity.class);
            Usuario usuario = getIntent().getParcelableExtra("usuario");
            intent.putExtra("usuario", usuario);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });

    btnEditarImagemPerfil = findViewById(R.id.btnEditarFotoPerfil);
    btnEditarImagemPerfil.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(EditarPerfilActivity.this, Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(EditarPerfilActivity.this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE},1);
                return;
            }
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,
                    android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
            startActivityForResult(intent, RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE);

        }
    });

    btnAlterarSenha = findViewById(R.id.btnAlterarSenha);
    btnAlterarSenha.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(EditarPerfilActivity.this, TelaAlterarSenhaActivity.class);
            Usuario usuario = getIntent().getParcelableExtra("usuario");
            intent.putExtra("usuario", usuario);
            startActivity(intent);
            
        }
    });

    btnSalvarPerfil = findViewById(R.id.btnSalvarPerfil);
    btnSalvarPerfil.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(EditarPerfilActivity.this, TelaPerfilActivity.class);
            Usuario usuario = getIntent().getParcelableExtra("usuario");
            intent.putExtra("usuario", usuario);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });

}

// convert from bitmap to byte array
public static byte[] getBytes(Bitmap bitmap) {
    ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 0, stream);
    return stream.toByteArray();
}

// convert from byte array to bitmap
public static Bitmap getImage(byte[] image) {
    return BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(image, 0, image.length);
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (requestCode == RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE && resultCode == RESULT_OK && null !=data){
        Uri selectedImageUri = data.getData();
        fotoUsuario.setImageURI(selectedImageUri);
        Drawable drawable = fotoUsuario.getDrawable();
        Bitmap bitmap = ((BitmapDrawable) drawable).getBitmap();
        byte[] image = getBytes(bitmap);
        Usuario usuario = getIntent().getParcelableExtra("usuario");
        Imagem imagem = new Imagem();
        imagem.setNome(usuario.getNome());
        imagem.setImagem(image);
        dao.insert(usuario.getNome(),image);


    }
```

**This is my DAO class**

```
public ImagemDAO(Context context){
    conexao = new Conexao(context);
    db = conexao.getWritableDatabase();
}

public void insert( String name, byte[] image) throws SQLiteException {
    ContentValues values = new  ContentValues();
    values.put("nome",    name);
    values.put("imagem",   image);
    db.insert( "imagem_perfil", null, values );
}


public Imagem select(String nome) throws SQLiteException{

    Cursor cursor = db.query("imagem_perfil", new String[] {
                    "nome", "imagem"}, "nome" + "=?",
            new String[] { String.valueOf(nome) }, null, null, null, null);
    if (cursor != null){
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        byte[] image = cursor.getBlob(1);


        Imagem imagem = new Imagem(cursor.getString(0), image);

        return imagem;
    }


    return null;
}

public int update(Imagem imagem) {
    ContentValues values = new  ContentValues();
    values.put("nome", imagem.getNome());
    values.put("imagem", imagem.getImagem());

    // updating row
    return db.update("imagem_perfil", values, "nome" + " = ?",
            new String[] { String.valueOf(imagem.getNome()) });
}

public void delete(Imagem imagem) {
    db.delete("imagem_perfil", "id" + " = ?",
            new String[] { String.valueOf(imagem.getNome()) });
    db.close();
}
```

**This is how I create the table on Database onCreate**

```
db.execSQL("create table imagem_perfil(nome varchar (50), " + "imagem BLOB)");
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (requestCode == IMAGE_UPLOAD_CODE) {
            Uri selectedImageUri = null;
            if (data != null) {
                selectedImageUri = data.getData();
            }
            InputStream inputStream = null;
            try {
                inputStream = getContentResolver().openInputStream(selectedImageUri);
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            Bitmap mImage = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(inputStream);
            imagem.setImageBitmap(mImage);
            dao.insert(usuario.getNome(),image);
        }
    }
```